# ngModel.$setValidity only works once

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation, angularjs-directive, datepicker

I'm currently working on a angular bootstrap ui datepicker popup validation, the thing is that I can set the max a min date and validate that (only when the user set the date by clicking on the calendar), but when the user writes the date by hand those validation are useless, I made a directive for that but only validates and sets the error once, here is my markup

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-3 m-t-b-20">
    <label>Date validation</label>
    <p class="input-group col-md-12">

      <input id="validationDate"
             type="text"
             name="validationDate"
             class="form-control"
             uib-datepicker-popup="{{ Ctrl.format }}"
             data-ng-model="Ctrl.formObj.validationDate"
             is-open="Ctrl.validationDate.opened"
             datepicker-options="Ctrl.dateOptions"
             ng-required="true"
             close-text="Close"
             placeholder="Fecha de radicacion"
             ng-click="Ctrl.openDatePicker('validationDate')"
             required
             date-validate/>

      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-default"
                ng-click="Ctrl.openDatePicker('validationDate')"
                data-ng-disabled="Ctrl.blockFields">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
      </span>

    </p>

    <!-- THE ERROR TO SHOW -->
    <p data-ng-show="stepOne.validationDate.$error.validbound"
       class="text-red">
      the selected date exeeds the max and min date boundaries
    </p>
  </div>
```

and this is my directive

```
var dateValidate = function () {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {

        elem.bind('keyup', function(value) {

            var atrvls = scope.$eval(attr.datepickerOptions),
                maxDate = moment(atrvls.maxDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                minDate = moment(atrvls.minDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                cDate = moment(elem.val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY', true);

            ngModel.$setValidity('validbound', true);

            if (!cDate.isValid()) {
                return false;
            }

            if (!cDate.isBetween(minDate, maxDate)) {
                ngModel.$setValidity('validbound', false);
            }

        });

    }
};
```

};

i would like to know why the validation is made only the first time, and tafter that the directive does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things here.

First, the dates given in Moment's `isBetween()` are exclusive, whereas the `datePicker`'s `minDate` and `maxDate` are inclusive dates. So you'll want to pass additional parameters to include these min and max dates within the range:

```
cDate.isBetween(minDate, maxDate, null, '[]')
```

Secondly, if you're looking for immediate feedback for whether the date is within the range then you'll need to wrap `$setValidity` inside a `scope.$apply` function.

Without looking at the javascript for the Datepicker Popup I can't say exactly why that is needed, but from experiments I can see that it only applies the `ng-invalid-validbound` attribute when the popup closes (whereas the `ng-valid-validbound` is applied as soon as validity is set to true). I assume this is this way for performance, since you can't select an out-of-bounds date using the popup anyway, you can only go the other way - from an invalid date to selecting a valid date using the popup.

This is more or less how I'd do it:

```
var dateValidate = function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
      elem.bind('keyup', function(value) {

        var atrvls = scope.$eval(attr.datepickerOptions),
          maxDate = moment(atrvls.maxDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
          minDate = moment(atrvls.minDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
          cDate = moment(elem.val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY', true);

        if (!cDate.isValid()) {
          scope.$apply(ngModel.$setValidity('validbound', null));
          return false;
        }

        if (!cDate.isBetween(minDate, maxDate, null, '[]')) {
          scope.$apply(ngModel.$setValidity('validbound', false));
        } else {
          scope.$apply(ngModel.$setValidity('validbound', true));
        }

      });
    }
  };
};
```

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/toXpEWNa99o7Gfs69KfZ?p=preview

Comment: nop, well... yes... but I forgot to mention that is made with angular 1.6.1, I change it on the plnker and didn't work when you type the date by hand

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I have updated the plunk to 1.6.1 and for me typing the date `15/02/2017` shows up green (in range) and typing `25/02/2017` shows red (out of range). I'm using Firefox, although I wouldn't expect it to be browser dependent

Comment: using firefox also, if I type "12/12/2018" the input turns red, if I delete rhe last character it turns normal, thats the expected behavior that I'm searching for, but if after that I type "12/12/2016" again (in range) the input turns red

Comment: "12/12/2016" is not in range which is why it goes red. The range I set was 04/02/2017 to 22/02/2017

Comment: Otherwise, if you want the border to stay the normal colour when in range, and only show red when it isn't then remove the `#validationDate.ng-valid-validbound` green border CSS rule in the Plunk

Comment: how do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

In the link function - create a validate function with your custom validation and you can add $watch on ngModel.$viewValue

```
scope.$watch(function () {
             return ngModel.$viewValue;
         }, validate);
```

Instead of 'Keyup' i think 'blur' would be better.

Comment: ok, thats an option, but I'm still not getting why the validation loses after the first validation